# Why is my Mac sleeping despite me using IdleSystemSleepDisabled

Tags: macos, foundation, xamarin.mac

I'm starting my activity with these options:

```
UserInitiated | IdleSystemSleepDisabled | AutomaticTerminationDisabled | Background | LatencyCritical
```

I can't ever have my app *nap*, regardless of whether it's the OS forcing it to nap or as a result of system sleep.

Now those `ProcessInfo` options seem to do the trick in all situations, except when I close the lid with no power or external display connected (although I haven't tried what happens with these two things connected).

Soon after I put the laptop in this state, my app begins to nap - it doesn't keep printing a message every second as per my test. The system is likely sleeping.

As per Apple's documentation, I would've thought `IdleSystemSleepDisabled` would ensure this didn't happen:

> Flag to prevent idle sleep.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Hi , do you mean want app  to continue to run in the background ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I'd like it to run regardless of whether it was active or backgrounded  when the user closes the lid. It still carries on running however it's not given sufficient resources to run smoothly; the behaviour I'm seeing is that of app nap.

Comment: Okey , have a look at this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks) , may be helpful .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks, but that's for iOS right? I'm developing a MacOS app. Sorry, I've added the wrong tag for the question. Will change...

Comment: Oh , sorry , that's for iOS application. I will continue to check the solution for MacOS .